# Unknown column error in MySQL (#1054)

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1054

This sql fails:

```
select * from RRICallouts as r 
    JOIN LevelToCalloutsJT as lc on ( `r.__kp_RecID` = `lc._kf_RecID~Callout` ) 
    JOIN Levels as l ON ( `lc._kf_RecID~Level` = `l.__kp_RecID` ) 
  where `l.__kp_RecID` = 201006221644060009

#1054 - Unknown column 'l.__kp_RecID' in 'where clause
```

This works:

```
select `__kp_RecID` from Levels as l ;
```

Using MySQL 5.0.77 on some linux variant

Comment: have you tried deleting different parts of the query and then re-testing it to isolate the problem? ie try it with out the WHERE statement, then try it without the second JOIN etc..

Comment: Does the equivilent SQL query here also fail?

select * from RRICallouts as r, Levels as l
    JOIN LevelToCalloutsJT as lc on ( `r.__kp_RecID` = `lc._kf_RecID~Callout` ) 
  where `l.__kp_RecID` = 201006221644060009 AND
`lc._kf_RecID~Level` = `l.__kp_RecID`

Comment: I do not envy you having to work on a database with such memorable column names. Is this a Hungarian goulash?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  +1 for a well-written question: Here's what I'm doing; Here's what I tried; Here's what happened that I don't understand.  Meets all the guidelines :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your backticks. You should use them as follows:

```
`r`.`__kp_RecID`
```

... instead of:

```
`r.__kp_RecID`
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, value int);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 100);

SELECT `t`.`id` FROM test AS t;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT `t.id` FROM test AS t;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: backticks was the problem. many thanks. the column names are truly messy, but the db name (provided by the host) is even better - 481986_G5ikr6eJy9wmxRm0

Comment: I don't envy you that, either!